# Calling a function using a list in my argument. Why is the return type a tuple?

Tags: python, list, class, tuples

```
def get_age_and_name(user_data):
  age = user_data[2]
  name = user_data[0]
  return age, name

user = ["Ann", "Davis", 35]
print(get_age_and_name(user))
```

#Q1)   user is a list but my return is a tuple.  Why?  i think it should be a list because of parameter.     #Q2) I am trying to find the class of local variable 'age' but getting a non-defined error in VS Code

```
print (type(age))
```

Q#1) I was expecting return class type to be a list      Q#2)  I was exepcting age type to be a list but I get an error

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
return age, name
```

is equivalent to:

```
return (age, name)
```

It constructs a two-element tuple whose first element is `age` and whose second element is `name`, and returns it.  That's the normal way for a function to return multiple values in Python.

If you want to unpack the values in the caller, you can call it as:

```
age, name = get_age_and_name(user)
```

This will set `age` to the first element of the tuple and `name` to the second element of the tuple.  You can, of course, also just use the return value as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Q1) If more than one value is returned from a function, Python will naturally return them as a tuple. The input value does not define a function's output. You can define a list as the data type you want by simply wrapping your values in square brackets like this:

```
  def get_age_and_name(user_data):  
  age = user_data[2] 
  name = user_data[0]  
  return [age, name]
```

Q2) In your example, age is a local variable, meaning it's defined in a function. That variable cannot be called outside of that function. That is why you're receiving the not-defined error. You can try printing the type of the variable within the function or if you want it outside the function try something like: `print(type(user[2]))` or `print(type(get_age_and_name(user)[0]))`

Both would have similar results. Hope this helps.